# asp.net mvc 5 windows authentication workaround

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

*updated*

I am working with a project (lets call it **project A**) which runs on ASP.MVC 5 and uses *Windows Authentication* in order to proceed with its users. **project A** has **db A** behind it. Also there is totally separated **project B**. It is a console application, which has its database (**db B**).
I need regularly update **db B** so that it would store some actual data from **db A**. I can modify **project A** source code, so that to create an API, but creating a shared DLL (e.g. shared data access layer library) is not possible due to security reasons. Still *Windows Authentication* in **project A** is applied due to security purposes, and could not be turned off.

The question is how can I get through windows authentication from *project B* to *project A*? 
**AllowAnonymousAttribute** applied to **Controller** in *project A* does not make it possible.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why would project B (Web API) need to access an action method on project A (MVC)? It should go the other way around (if at all). If you need to access the same functionality of project A, then why not make a shared DLL?

Comment: **Project B** not necessarily has to be the Web API. Lets say that **project B** is a console application, which has its database (**db B**). Also there is **project A** which is essentially is a MVC 5 application and has **db A** behind it. I need regularly to update **db B** so that it would store some actual data from **db A**. 
I can modify **project A** source code, so that to create an API, but creating a shared DLL (e.g. shared data access layer library) is not possible due to security reasons. Still _Win. Auth._ is applied due to security purposes, and could not be turned off.

Comment: That info is more helpful. Although, I highly recommend you **edit your question** to add that information. Not every person who answers bothers to read the comments and you will be more likely to receive a satisfactory answer if all of the details are present in the question.

Comment: @NightOwl888 okay, thanks for advice!